# In Javascript, can you return a function and then evaluate it within the outer scope?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Apps Script in which I am using a self-made library to handle common tasks.

Can I call a helper function from another function (in this case, the doGet() function which is called as a standard http request when you publish the app), and evaluate it's return value in the outer scope?

To be clear, I want doGet(e) to return a 403 if the "testgroup" doesn't have the proper permissions. Otherwise, I want it to render "HI THERE". And this is because what the doGet(e) function returns is what is rendered in the browser.

Hope it's clearer now.

**Edit:** Rewrote the whole question.

function A:

```
function doGet(e) {

  TARS.Security.permissionGateway("testgroup");

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("HI THERE");

}
```

function B:

```
Security.permissionGateway = function(group) {
  if (Security.activeUserBelongsToGroup(group)) {
    return TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403);
  }
}
```

Comment: ...`if( !B() ) return false;`?

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Another option would be to throw an exception, but that's its own can of worms...

Comment: Even with your clarification, the concept and code would still work pretty much the same way. What exactly does `TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403)` return that you need to check for?

Comment: It still seems like Jon Surell's suggestion answers your question. Try pointing out any relevant information as to why that's not a solution.

Comment: `TARS_Errors.throwErrorPage(403)` returns an HTML output.

Comment: And if `Security.permissionGateway(group)` is OK it returns `undefined`? Your check will probably need to be something like `typeof B() !== 'undefined'`, or maybe you should always return something from `B` if that's an option.

Comment: @JonSurrell i guess if OK return _undefined_

Comment: I rewrote the whole question. Made no sense trying to keep up a horrible example. Any thoughts now?

Comment: Still not seeing the issue. *If permissionGateway returns something that indicates a failure, do not continue with current function...*: `if (...permissionGateway() == /* failure value */) return /* failure value */`...

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question seems very straightforward, you just want to set a condition in `a` on the return of `b`:

```
function a() {
  var returnValueB = b();
  if (returnValueB === false) {
    return false;
  }
  // do more stuff if b() didn't return false
}

function b() {
  // we really don't care...
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems excessive to use a variable for a single check.

Comment: @Juhana it's not production code :) My goal was clarity.

Comment: @JonSurrell I just added some information. Check it out.